# pytorch dataloader- RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, resnet, torchvision

I'm trying resnet implementation from scratch.

This error occurred during training after setting the dataset in Dataloader:

```
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 224, 224] at entry 0 and [1, 224, 224] at entry 25
```

Usually, I know why this message displayed. It's about unequal image dataset

But before I got this message, I apply transforms so I didn't expect error like this.

Sometimes the message [4,224,224] appears instead of [1,224,224].

Of course, I checked dataset all images are color

Here's the code

```
## Class declaration, transforms codes are applied __getitem__()

class cnd_data(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, file_path, train=True, transforms=None):

        self.train=train
        self.transforms=transforms

        self.cat_img_path=os.path.join(file_path, 'data\kagglecatsanddogs\PetImages\Cat')
        self.dog_img_path=os.path.join(file_path, 'data\kagglecatsanddogs\PetImages\Dog')
        
        self.cat_list=natsort.natsorted(glob.glob(self.cat_img_path + '/*.jpg'))
        self.dog_list=natsort.natsorted(glob.glob(self.dog_img_path + '/*.jpg'))
 

        if self.train==True:
            self.imgn_list=self.cat_list[:12000]+self.dog_list[:12000]
            self.img_label=[0]*12000+[1]*12000

        else:
            self.imgn_list=self.cat_list[12000:]+self.dog_list[12000:]
            self.img_label=[0]*500+[1]*500

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_label)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):

        image_data=Image.open(self.imgn_list[idx])

        print(self.imgn_list[idx])
        if self.transforms:
            sample=self.transforms(image_data)

        return sample, self.img_label[idx]


## And transforms setting codes
transforms=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(size=(224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor()])
```

Comment: Does the dataset contain any labels or targets? if there is a mismatch between the data and the labels that can cause this error.

Comment: @FunnyChef  Thanks for the reply.
The dataset used is catndogs in kaggle, and the images have names ranging from 0 to 12,499 in dogs and cats folders, respectively.
__init__() reads the image path from 0 to 11,999 in each folder, and then sets the cat to 0 and dog to 1 label according to the number of images, so I think it's likely not a related issue.
If you think the mismatch between label and data will be a problem as mentioned, could you explain how this error occurs?

Comment: Did you check the [1,224,224] sample? This can't be properly colored image. Either is b/w or one of the RGB channels. In contrast, [4,224,224] goes beyond the common 3 RGB channels.

Comment: @Christian Yeah, actually I tried to train my model several time and checked what image occurs error. But all checked images are color image. In addition, the dataset description also states that channel is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pytorch expects any data sample to has the same size after preprocessing, so that it can be stacked to a single tensor. According to your error log, `[3, 224, 224]` seems to refer to a RGB image; `[1, 224, 224]` is grayscale and `[4, 224, 224]` is RGBA (has alpha channel for opacity). If you use PIL Image, make sure to convert it to RGB before apply any transform.

```
Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already solved the problem same way. But I didn't think to write down a detailed solution, but I think it became a better article because you wrote it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Um... I checked that the problem was that the code I wrote when I read the image from PIL was not able to read the color image with bit-depth 8 as desired. **If bit-depth is 8, this is because PIL.Image.open() recognizes and treats the channel as one.**

When the data set was created, the data were collected in various forms, so it seems that although most of the data were 24-bit color images, it contained some 8-bit data (if the channel was 4, it was a 32-bit color image, because RGB added alpha channel was added)

Anyway, this problem will be solved by checking the function that converts it to three channels if it is entered in 8-bit color. I'll have to look at the data more carefully from now on. Thank you to everyone who commented.